# Vertical align issues! Absolute positioning. Can't get it to work

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one displaying over the other through absolute positioning. I can't get the vertical align to work. I read a bunch of different ways to do it and still can't figure it out. This method below seems to be one of the more popular ways of doing it but it still doesn't work!

The actual HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="header_slider_container">
<div class="header_slider_wrapper">

<div id="form_side">
<div id="form_side_div">
<h2 id="form_side_title">GET IN TOUCH WITH US</h2>
[form code goes here]
</div>
</div>

<div id="slider_side">
[slider code goes here]
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

The slider code automatically fills in the width of the space (100% width) and the height is more or less around 500px when the browser is maximized. As the browser starts shrinking so does the slider. But I can take care of that later through media queries. I just need to get the vertical align working first.

The form code just fits into the container to whatever size it needs which is more or less 400x300.

The CSS looks like this:

```
.header_slider_container {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: 89px;
}

.header_slider_wrapper {
    width:100%; 
    background: orange; 
}

#form_side {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 30%;
}

#form_side_div {
    padding: 0 15px;
    background: rgba(22,22,22,0.5);
}

#form_side_title {
    color: #006298; 
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#slider_side {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Tell me why I'm an idiot, please!

EDIT: Here is an image for added clarity. The Form (inside that dark background) needs to be vertically centered to the height of the slider behind it. [image]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on what you need? Are you trying to align the left edge of both the divs?

Comment: @Harry similar to that, yes. Trying to get #form_side to float ON TOP OF #slider_side towards the left side. So think of a rectangle and that's #slider_size. Now think of a square about 300px X 300px and that's #form_size. I want to place the square over the rectangle without effecting the rectangle's position on the page. And then I want to vertical align the square to the rectangle's height. Would an image help better? I can create a quick one.

Comment: @AdrianoBatista, did you ever find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple ways to center all of your content both horizontally and vertically.

**Technique One (demo at http://jsbin.com/mahuj/1/edit):**

```
.header_slider_container {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* margin-top: 89px; */
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%; /* Can be any % or px. Defaults to 100%. */
  height: 50%; /* Can be any % or px. Defaults to 100%. */
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header_slider_wrapper {
  width:100%; 
  background: orange; 
}

#form_side {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 30%;
}

#form_side_div {
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: rgba(22,22,22,0.5);
}

#form_side_title {
  color: #006298; 
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#slider_side {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

**Technique Two (demo at http://jsbin.com/lunuq/1/edit):**

```
.header_slider_container {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* margin-top: 89px; */
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px; /* Must declare a size. Can't use %. */
  height: 200px; /* Must declare a size. Can't use %. */
  position: absolute; /* Or fixed. */
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.header_slider_wrapper {
  width:100%; 
  background: orange; 
}

#form_side {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 30%;
}

#form_side_div {
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: rgba(22,22,22,0.5);
}

#form_side_title {
  color: #006298; 
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#slider_side {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Here's your HTML again, but with indentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="header_slider_container">
      <div class="header_slider_wrapper">

        <div id="form_side">
          <div id="form_side_div">

          <h2 id="form_side_title">GET IN TOUCH WITH US</h2>
          [form code goes here]

          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slider_side">
        [slider code goes here]
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```